# Is there any analytical proof of Newton's law of gravitation?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity

Is there any analytical proof of [Newton's law of gravitation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton's_law_of_universal_gravitation)? May be through electromagnetic theory we can derive the proof but is there some other method.

Comment: Electric fields and magnetism are related through Maxwell's equations. If gravity could be added then you'd be a step closer to the "theory of everything" or the "grand unification theory".   So the only justification for gravity is experimental observations.

Comment: Physics is not math. What do you mean by 'analytical proof'?

Comment: A proof proceeding *from what axioms*? Ultimately, every physical theory contains some statements taken as axioms based on experimental fact which cannot be "proven". In Newtonian gravity, the law of gravitation is usually taken to be such an axiom, so it is unclear what you expect from an answer here.

Answer (score 2):

As a general rule you cannot prove a physical theory because physical theories are based upon assumptions. You can show rigorously that the theory follows from the assumptions you have made, but at the end of the day your assumptions could be wrong. The only way to test this is to do experiments and see if your theory gives the correct answer.

Having said this, Newton's law of gravity comes closer than many theories to the ideal of being derived from as few assumptions as possible. Newton's law can be derived from General Relativity, and General Relativity is pretty much based on a single assumption i.e. [general covariance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_covariance).

We can't prove that the assumption of general covariance is correct, but if it is correct then Newton's law is an inevitable result in the low velocity low energy density limit.